# How to find next of next line in a table - oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence, lead

I have a large table and for every line, I show the values of the next line using "lead" function.
But i want to show the "next-next", which means the values of the next line of the next line.
I can't find a way to do it in one insert query (there is no lead(lead)).
Any ideas?
This is the structure of this function:
LEAD(return_value ,offset [,default])
OVER (
[PARTITION BY partition_expression, ... ]
ORDER BY sort_expression [ASC | DESC], ...
)
Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 4):

Just pass in "2" as the second argument to `lead()`:

```
lead(<col>, 2) over ( . . . )
```